# add blocks in text input box, similar to email applications to field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to code following header for a compose message page in a web application, using HTML, CSS, and JS.

[image]

My question is how can i add functionality to input box to convert selected email addresses to a box as shown in following image:

[image]

Similar functionality is used in almost every email application these days.

Same functionality is used on Tags textbox on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using jQuery **Tag it!** plugin.

[Link](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/tag-it)

[Demo](http://levycarneiro.com/projects/tag-it/example.html)

Even this plugin is superb : [**AutoSuggest**](https://github.com/drewwilson/AutoSuggest) | [**Demo**](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, this is almost what i needed. Only issue with this plugin is that i can not add space in names. any suggestions please?

Comment: usually tags don't have spaces, nor do email addresses. Technically they are not doing anything inside an input field. Its rewriting an unordered list to make it look like an input field.